# Prove by Vitali cover: Arbitrary union of sets with non-empty interiors is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on the Vitali Covering Lemma. I'd like to see a demonstration of the statement in the title.

I'm looking for a demonstration of the fact that an arbitrary union of sets (each with non-empty interior) is Lebesgue measurable in $R^n$ using the Vitali Covering Lemma.

Even just a paper or links to other works are acceptable, and it doesn't matter if you're not directly answering. I've browsed past questions without finding any useful results. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but a special case of it: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43721/is-arbitrary-union-of-closed-balls-in-rn-lebesgue-measurable.

Comment: Perhaps first use VCL to show the arbitrary union of closed balls is measurable.  At least that one is true...

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not true. Any non-measurable set is a union of its one-point subsets.

**Edit:**

For the revised question (with non-empty interiors), the result is still false. Consider the simplest case of Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $V$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$, and consider the sets (for each $v\in V$):

$$U_v = \{v\} \cup [2,3]$$

Then each set $U_v$ has non-empty interior, but the union of all the sets $U_v$ is just $V \cup [2,3]$, which is non-measurable, since $V$ is non-measurable.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake while traslating the statement in english. The sets are not just non-empty (for which your answer works) but with interior non-empty (so excluding the singletons for exemple)